# How to replace a forward slash into backward slash in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace forward slash to backward slash i tried this`string.replace.("/", "\\" )`but it shows like this `C:\wdir/ReduxFlow.jpg` workout any idea?

Comment: already answer question looks like normal string but slash treats differently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`split` and `join` on `/` and `\` respectively.

```js
var string="a/b/c/s";

console.log(string.split('/').join('\\'))
```

Comment: upvote and mark it as correct so it can help others too

Comment: "a/b/c/s".replace(/\//g,'\\') would be better

Comment: @UtillYou how would you define _"better"_?

Comment: @Phil using regular expression has better performance and better readability

Comment: @UtillYou can you link to a benchmark test? [This one](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1557/0/regex-vs-splitjoin) disagrees with you. Readability is subjective

Comment: I didn't make a benchmark before. But I run test on this [benchmark](http://jsben.ch/LFfWA) several times. It seems these two methods have similar performance. But readability is very obvious. Since regular expression explicitly tells reader that we are replacing something.